# Rails form_tag with RESTFul params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a `new_words` controller and now I want to have a 'search' action.

I want Rails to return list of search results when navigate to this link `new_words/search/"search_word_here"`

In my routes, I got this:

```
resources :new_words do
        collection do        
            get 'search/:word', action: :search, as: 'search'
        end
    end
```

And in view I have a form with `get` method.

```
<%= form_tag search_new_words_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :word %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

But I only get this error:

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `:word` as a keyword in your route `get 'search/:word'`, Rails is expecting that you provide that value in order to build the URL:

```
search_new_words_path("test")
#=> "/new_words/search/test"
```

In your question however, you're expecting that a form will supply `:word`, which means you should be using a form parameter, instead of a keyword in a route:

**routes**:

```
resources :new_words do
    collection do        
        get 'search', action: :search, as: 'search'
    end
end
```

**view:**

```
<%= form_tag search_new_words_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :word %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

And then in your controller you can use the `params` method to get the search word:

```
def search
  params[:word] # will return the search word
end
```

Comment: So, can't I have full restful route in this situation, right ?

Comment: and simple way show route prefix `bin/rails routes`

Comment: Not while using a form helper like that. You'd have to use JS to programmatically submit the form to the correct URL if you want to keep the keyword as part of the route. If you want to support both, you could create two different end points, or make the `:word` part of the URL optional and use the query param if it's empty. But all of those options are added complexity in my opinion, so might not be worth it depending on your use case.